# Wand Rounded Edges on Images

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian, wand

I've been scratching my head for a few days on how to complete the task of making the edges rounded on an image taken from picamera using python-wand. I have it setup now to where it grabs the image and composites it over the banner/background image with the following:

```
img = Image(filename=Picture)                                         
img.resize(1200, 800)
bimg = Image(filename=Background)
bimg.composite(img, left=300, top=200)
bimg.save(filename=BPicture)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`wand.drawing.Drawing.rectangle`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.rectangle) to generate rounded corners, and overlay it with composite channels.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing

with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.resize(240, 160)
    with Image(width=img.width,
               height=img.height,
               background=Color("white")) as mask:

        with Drawing() as ctx:
            ctx.fill_color = Color("black")
            ctx.rectangle(left=0,
                          top=0,
                          width=mask.width,
                          height=mask.height,
                          radius=mask.width*0.1)  # 10% rounding?
            ctx(mask)
        img.composite_channel('all_channels', mask, 'screen')
        img.save(filename='/tmp/out.png')
```

[image: Wand rounded edges]

Now if I understand your question, you can apply the same technique, but composite `Picture` in the drawing context.

```py
with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.resize(240, 160)
    with Image(img) as nimg:
        nimg.negate()  # For fun, let's negate the image for the background
        with Drawing() as ctx:
            ctx.fill_color = Color("black")
            ctx.rectangle(left=0,
                          top=0,
                          width=nimg.width,
                          height=nimg.height,
                          radius=nimg.width*0.3)  # 30% rounding?
            ctx.composite('screen', 0, 0, nimg.width, nimg.height, img)
            ctx(nimg)
        nimg.save(filename='/tmp/out2.png')
```

[image: Wand rounded edges with background]